# jQuery checkbox validation in same class

Tags: jquery, validation, checkbox

I wonder if I can validate checkbox can be selected with only one option based on each question like the radio button.
However, I am using the same class for all checkboxes even though they have different titles.

Is it possible to validate each question rather than validating with the class name?
I would like to click only yes or no for each question.

Here is the HTML and Jquery code below.
Thanks in advance.

--- HTML ---

```
    <div><label class="k-checkbox-label" >Question 1</label> 
      <input type="checkbox" id="q1_yes" class="k-checkbox">
      <label class="k-checkbox-label" >Yes</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="q1_no" class="k-checkbox uk-margin-left">
      <label class="k-checkbox-label" >No</label>
    </div>
    <div><label class="k-checkbox-label" >Question 2</label> 
      <input type="checkbox" id="q2_yes" class="k-checkbox">
      <label class="k-checkbox-label" >Yes</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="q2_no" class="k-checkbox uk-margin-left">
      <label class="k-checkbox-label" >No</label>
    </div>
     <div><label class="k-checkbox-label" >Question 3</label> 
      <input type="checkbox" id="q3_yes" class="k-checkbox">
      <label class="k-checkbox-label" >Yes</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="q3_no"class="k-checkbox uk-margin-left">
      <label class="k-checkbox-label" >No</label>
    </div>
     <div><label class="k-checkbox-label" >Question 4</label> 
      <input type="checkbox" id="q4_yes" class="k-checkbox">
      <label class="k-checkbox-label" >Yes</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="q4_no" class="k-checkbox uk-margin-left">
      <label class="k-checkbox-label" >No</label>
    </div>
```

--- code ---

```
    $('input.k-checkbox').on('change', function() {
        $('input.k-checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
    });
```

Comment: *"like a radio button"* - why not used... a radio button?   **Path of least surprise** -  "ooh, here's some checkboxes, I can click multiple... why are the other **checkboxes** becoming unticked?*

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, it is the same action with a Radio button. But I need to use the check box for some reason. I would like to click only yes or no for each question.

Comment: FYI you can always style radio buttons to *look like* checkboxes (if you really must) - the point being if you use the correct control then you won't need *any* code.

Comment: Thansk for your comment, I need to discuss that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method, you can [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) the other checkbox to set its checked property to the opposite of the one that was clicked.

In other words, in the below snippet, the `!this.checked` is the opposite boolean value of the click checkbox... Applied on the other one.

```js
$("input.k-checkbox").on("click", function(){
  $(this).closest("div").find("input.k-checkbox").not(this).prop("checked", !this.checked)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label class="k-checkbox-label" >Question 1</label> 
  <input type="checkbox" id="q1_yes" class="k-checkbox">
  <label class="k-checkbox-label" >Yes</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="q1_no" class="k-checkbox uk-margin-left">
  <label class="k-checkbox-label" >No</label>
</div>
<div><label class="k-checkbox-label" >Question 2</label> 
  <input type="checkbox" id="q2_yes" class="k-checkbox">
  <label class="k-checkbox-label" >Yes</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="q2_no" class="k-checkbox uk-margin-left">
  <label class="k-checkbox-label" >No</label>
</div>
 <div><label class="k-checkbox-label" >Question 3</label> 
  <input type="checkbox" id="q3_yes" class="k-checkbox">
  <label class="k-checkbox-label" >Yes</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="q3_no"class="k-checkbox uk-margin-left">
  <label class="k-checkbox-label" >No</label>
</div>
 <div><label class="k-checkbox-label" >Question 4</label> 
  <input type="checkbox" id="q4_yes" class="k-checkbox">
  <label class="k-checkbox-label" >Yes</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="q4_no" class="k-checkbox uk-margin-left">
  <label class="k-checkbox-label" >No</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it is perfectly working. :)